# AngularJS <ui-select> is shaking up a bit on selecting

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ui-select

**Adding a search-enabled to UI-select is causing the dropdown to shake up a bit.**

```html
<ui-select
  ng-model="$ctrl.savedFilter"
  theme="bootstrap"
  title="Filter"
  search-enabled="$ctrl.searchEnabled"
  on-select="$ctrl.loadFilter($item, $model)"
>
  <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="{{savedFiltersPlaceholder}}">
    {{$select.selected.description}}
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices
    repeat="filter in savedFilters | propsFilter: {description: $select.search}"
  >
    <small
      ng-bind-html="filter.description | highlight: $select.search"
    ></small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

[image: gif for reference]

I tried doing CSS changes and also tried without data still the jerking up keeps happening.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this has to do with the size of the parent element and not with the `ui-select`. Check your CSS code and make the parent element the size of the box after the dropdown has extended.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I even tried doing that but no luck

Comment: can you try and recreate it in a jsfiddle ? Always inspect the parent element pre and post click, see how the styling changes. I've had a similar error with other JS Frameworks and that's how I solved it.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I was able to overcome this jerk issue with append-to-body =" true" but it's cutting the placeholder field a bit and it's also taking to another problem, when this dropdown is kept open without selecting any option and try to select another dropdown, the other one is shaking up when selecting , now I'm back to square one.